# Do i need multiple binaries to support multi-resolution windows 8 application?

Tags: windows-8

I am developing a windows 8 application but this application need to be supported on multiple resolution & density screens (tablet, notebook & desktop). Do i need to create multiple binaries for each resolution?
i've looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh780612 but need the clarification before i jump into a solution.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're designing according to the [Windows Store UX Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465424.aspx), you don't need separate binaries, but you do need to have scaled versions of all graphics, logos, etc. and you need to handle orientation and layout changes in your app so that you always present a suitable UI.

We're going through this pain now, and it's very very tempting to design some static layouts, with fixed positions etc. but that's very much against the Windows Store guidelines. It's probably going to take just as long to do the design as it is to do the code.

If you're using HTML5/Javascript, there is [a useful example of an adaptive layout on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150600.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

No you don't. Generally it'll just work. You can optionally provide high-resolution images by using a scale naming convention as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx

I recommend that you use the Simulator option when you run the app to test the app looks good at different resolutions and dpi settings.